# Does the phrase "under ground" exist?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Assume a game where armies fight against each other. There are five factions A, B, C, D, and E. Let faction B ask faction A "*Where are their armies?*" (the armies of the allied factions C, D and E).

Would saying "*there man, under ground*" be correct to imply that faction A has already beaten their armies?

Comment: I'm not sure what _man_ refers to in your quote. You could be trying to say, _Their men are underground_ (in which case you are using the wrong _there_), or you could be using man as an exclamation: _There, man, under ground_, in which case you really need a comma after the word _there_, and _underground_ should be one word).

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'under' and 'ground' as two different words. They *do* exist but then you need the definite article ***'the'***. So, it could be 'under *the* ground'.

Now, ['underground' is also a word (single)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/underground_1?q=underground) which means under the surface of the ground.

Whether 'beaten' is considered as 'defeating **and killing**' both, you need to say that they are 'under the ground **buried**'. Without the article and explaining *what exactly you want to say,* 'under ground' will be considered 'underground', and listeners may consider that you are talking about the army which is under the ground -in some [*bunker*!](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bunker_1?q=bunker)

Comment: [I think the ngram is interesting](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+under+ground%2Care+underground&year_start=1785&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3). Nowadays, _under ground_ is almost always compounded, but, apparently, it wasn't that way 150 years ago. (Most of the modern hits for _under ground_ in that ngram are actually quotes from 19th-century works.)

Comment: Nice idea. The setting of the game are the middle ages.

Comment: I think _Their men are underground_ **could** be used as a euphemism for _Their armies are defeated_, although, as Maulik says, there is plenty of room for confusion, too. It's not a standard idiom, and it could mean they are hiding in a cave or a tunnel. Also, you could separate _underground_ into two words in light of the fact that _underground_ is a relatively recent word, but I'd be careful with that. Unless the rest of thy game useth antiquated English, gamers are likely to reckon that as a typo, not a clever hearkening back to days of yore.

Comment: You could say they're "in the ground", which makes it clearer that you're saying they're dead in a dramatic way, without the other possible meanings of "underground" (literally underground or just gone into hiding).